# Where Jenkins holds project's files?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I am tring to build c++ project using Jenkins on Ubuntu server.
In build logs current project path is specified as /var/jenkins_home/myproject

However, when I checked this path, there is no such folder in my server.

So where the Jenkins actually holds project files?

Answer (score 0):

You can always print the WORKSPACE environment variable value during a build for debugging:

Add a build step to execute shell script and write the following line:

```
echo $WORKSPACE
```

This will give you the path to your project files.